# Automatically pausing html5 video as the 'next' button is pressed (javascript/ jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, pause

I have designed an i-phone-like screen on a web browser where I am testing this application I am in the process of building. None of the videos have auto-play; the user can play the video by clicking on the video area.The user can navigate to the next video by clicking on the top right button.

[image]

**THE PROBLEM:**  The problem is if I pressed on a video and it is playing,if I press the 'next' button, if I have not clicked back on, the video continues to play as the new one advances, and I can hear the sound of it playing in the background.

**I HAVE TRIED TO MUTE THE VIDEOS BUT IT DID NOT WORK** I have tried muting the video if the user clicks on the 'next' button, and it works to mute it, BUT, the problem is that if I press the return button, the video is completely muted and unless I refresh the page, the sound will not play again at all*.

*This is the jquery code I used to try and mute the video if the 'next' button is pressed:*

```
$("#nextButtonTop, #prevButtonTop ").click( function (){
if( $("#topVid video:visible").prop('muted') ) {
        $("#topVid video:visible").prop('muted', true);

  } else {
    $("#topVid video:visible").prop('muted', true);


  }
});
```

*The basic html code for this section:*

```
<div class="topVid channel1960s">
  <div class="testMarqueeLeft"><div>CHANNEL 1960s: Jackie Kennedy at JFK's service</div></div>
      <video loop onclick="this.paused? this.play() : this.pause()" >
      <source src="videos/1960s_Jackie_mourning_VERT.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video> </div>
```

**IDEAL SOLUTION: PAUSING AS SOON AS THE 'NEXT' BUTTON IS PRESSED** ultimately, I realized that muting is not the ideal solution because of performance issues (the hidden video will keep playing even without the sound). ***What is the best way to pause (instead of muting) the video as soon with this 'next' button pressed?*** There is already inline javascript code on the html that will play and pause if the user clicks on it but **I am not sure how add this other part, where it pauses if the next button is pressed and it can be played once it is visible.**

I tried this to make the video pause but it did not work

```
$("#nextButtonTop, #prevButtonTop ").click( function (){
  if ($('.topVid.video').is(":hidden")) {
      $('.topVid.video').pause();
  }
});
```

I tried this as well and nothing

```
$('video').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":in-viewport")) {
        $(this)[0].play();
    } else {
        $(this)[0].pause();
    }
})
```

the use of

```
 "this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();"
```

was suggested on another answer but I am not sure how this could work given that the pausing would be triggered by clicking on another element (the 'next' button, not the video itself.

Comment: This question would be improved by including a description of a typical usage sequence before stating the problem.

Comment: I am building this, so there is no "typical" usage sequence yet:). This is what I wrote:   "the user can play the video by clicking on the video area. The problem is if I pressed on a video and it is playing,if I press the 'next' button, if I have not clicked back on, the video continues to play as the new one advances, and I can hear the sound of it playing in the background."  This only happens if I have clicked on the video and not clicked it back to pause it.  In other words, ideally the video would be pause automatically if the 'next' button is pressed.

Comment: you'll need the id/selector on the video itself and then call $(".video-selector").pause()

Comment: Looking better but it's still not clear why there should be two video windows or how the user is supposed to interact with them.

Comment: This is just the fraction that I needed help with. I have a separate button (not on this window) that is the "channel" button that displays the second window.  You are correct that the second window info is relevant (I took it for a separate question I posted a few days back that was about the second screen ). I will update the image. Btw I am not looking for UX critiques, just the info abt the video pause:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your jQuery is at the end of the document, remember to wrap it in `jQuery(function($) {...})`.

Attach all event handlers in javaScript, not HTML. This is not essential, but allows you to see all your interactive code in a single glance.

Stay aware that `.play()` and `.pause()` are `<video>` element methods, not jQuery methods.

Try this :

**HTML**

```
<div class="topVid channel1960s">
    <div class="testMarqueeLeft">
        <div>CHANNEL 1960s: Jackie Kennedy at JFK's service</div>
    </div>
    <video loop> <!-- remove onclick="..." -->
        <source src="videos/1960s_Jackie_mourning_VERT.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Attach click handler to both <video> elements
    $('video').on('click', function() {
        this.paused? this.play() : this.pause();
    });

    // Attach click handler to top video's prev/next buttons
    $("#nextButtonTop, #prevButtonTop").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // maybe not required but does no harm.
        var $video = $('.topVid video');
        if ($video.is(':hidden')) {
            $video.get(0).pause(); // .pause() is a method of the <video> element, not a jQuery method.
        }
    });
});
```